# Spurious Transaction errors in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I'm getting spurious errors when trying to `doInBackground` of an `AsyncTask` which I initiate in `MainActivity` when the user clicks `btnSearch`.

Here's the part of `doInBackground` where I might get no error, might get error after 1 transaction, might get error at record 23001 after 23 transactions. I got `returnCode < 0` after trying to `insertWord`.

``````
private class LoadDatabase extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void
{
  protected Void doInBackground(Object[] params)
  {
...
    my_openDb("DatabaseConnector.LoadDatabase.doInBackground");

    while(scDict.hasNext())
    {
        int kTransactions = 0;
        try
        {
            mDatabase.beginTransaction();

            while(kTransactions < MAX_TRANSACTIONS && scDict.hasNext())
            {
                s = scDict.next();
                count++;
                long returnCode = insertWord(s); // error here **********
                if(returnCode < 0)
                {
                    if(debug) Log.w("`````Abort--can't add <",s + "> at " + count + " with RC = " + returnCode + " and KT = " + kTransactions );
                    my_closeDb("DatabaseConnector.LoadDatabase.doInBackground DISASTER");//$$
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                ++ kTransactions;
            }
            mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch(Exception e){ Log.w("`````", "Exception " + e.toString()); }
        finally
        {
            mDatabase.endTransaction();
            publishProgress((Integer) (int) s.charAt(0));
        }
    } 
my_closeDb("doInBackground outer while ended");
``````

Method `insertWord`:

```
  long insertWord(String _word) 
  {
    long r = -1;
    ContentValues newWord = new ContentValues();
    newWord.put(WORD_COLUMN_NAME, _word);
    try {
  //  r = mDatabase.insert              (TABLE_NAME,null,newWord); 
      r = mDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME,null,newWord,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
            return r;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      if(debug)Log.w("DBC", "insert failed for <" + _word + ">");
      if(debug)Log.w("DBC", "exception " + e.toString());
      my_closeDb(DatabaseConnector.insertWord");
  }
    return -1 ; // -1 if can't insert
  }
```

The commented out line always worked in the past, until major overhaul to simplify code. (GREAT idea.)(NOT!) I got the idea of `insertWithOnConflict` from `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html` where they say `insertWithOnConflict` is the `General method for inserting a row into the database`.

Of course I got `insert` from a text book. AS says it's a `convenience method for inserting a row into the database`. But it does lack the algorithm for resolving conflicts. There shouldn't be any conflicts. I made the change to `insertWithOnConflict` when I got errors with `insert`.

That was probably my first warning that I was on thin ice.

I call `DatabaseConnector` from `MainActivity`, which calls inner classes: `DatabaseHelper`, which calls `LoadDatabase` and then `doInBackground`.

I'm not sure I should have an `AsyncTask` so directly connected to `MainActivity` because of Answers and comments suggesting concurrence issues might be a problem.

Another suggestion was to put the `AsyncTask` inside `MainActivity`. That would mean I'd have to move classes `DatabaseConnector` and its inner classes there, too. If it all seems overly-complicated, I just followed the big example in a textbook. But you must connect the database to the activity, and you do need help, and if the task MUST run in the background, so it must be `AsyncTask`, as I understand it.

Call from `MainActivity`:

```
dbc = new DatabaseConnector(MainActivity.this, getAssets(), databaseFileExists());
```

In DatabaseConnector:

```
  public DatabaseConnector(Context _context, AssetManager _assets, boolean dbExists)
  {
    mContext = _context;
    mDbOpenHelper = new DbOpenHelper(_context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    if( ! dbExists)
        createAndOrFillDb(db);
  }
```

`createAndOrFillDb`:

```
    void createAndOrFillDb(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
    ...
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + WORD_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT primary key );")
    //...
         cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, mColumns, null, null, null, null, WORD_COLUMN_NAME);
    //...
        LoadDatabase
            __loadDb;
            __loadDb = new LoadDatabase();
            __loadDb.execute((Object[]) null);
      }
```

So my questions are

(1) Do you think I'm getting spurious results during transactions in `doInBackground` because of it being in a class separate from `MainActivity` and if so, what can I do about it?

(2) Do you think I should just stick 1200 lines of code into `MainActivity`, resulting in a 2200-line monster so I won't have to worry about concurrency?

(3) Maybe initiate `doInBackground` from a thread separate from UI? (No clue how to control that, but I'm willing to try.)

(4) What else might you suggest?

Comment: No takers? Seriously? Too long? Unclear? I did my best to present it logically, top down,  ya know?